# Static variable prints the correct value but returns null

Tags: php, recursion, static

I have a strange situation. Have a look at this. I don't know why the $counter variable prints 6, but does not return 6.

```
function myTest($bin) {
    static $counter = 0;
    if ($bin == 0) {
        // echo $counter; // prints 6
        return $counter;
    }

    $rem = $bin % 2;

    if($rem == 0) {
        $counter++;
        $bin = $bin / 2;
        myTest($bin);
    }
    else {
        $counter++;
        $bin = $bin - 1;
        myTest($bin);
   }
}

$test = mytest(11);

var_dump($test); // Returns NULL
```

Comment: When writing recursive functions, you must "return" the recursive calls as in `return myTest($bin);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing recursive functions, you must "return" the recursive calls as in

```
return myTest($bin);
```

Without the return for the recursive calls, the original call to the function doesn't return anything. So, $test is null (nothing returned).